# How to get grouped routes in blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

How can I get grouped routes in a blade template?

The grouped routes in php look like:

routes.php

```
    ...
    //player section
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'test'], function() {

        Route::get('{slug}/{id}', [
            'uses' => 'TestController@getTest',
            'as' => 'getTest',
        ]);

        Route::get('{slug}/{id}/report', [
            'middleware' => 'auth',
            'uses' => 'TestController@reportTest',
            'as' => 'reportTest',
        ]);

    });
    ...
```

In a blade template I get single routes by it's `'as'` string like

```
@if(Route::is('playTest'))
<!-- some html here -->
@endif
```

But how can I get all the routes grouped by prefix `'test'`in a blade template?

I want to prevent to write all the routes by it's name like:

```
(Route::is('getTest', 'reportTest'))
```

Comment: Are you using `Route::is` or `Request::is`? I can't seem to find `Route::is` in the documentation.

Comment: @Samsquanch `Route::is` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
@if(Request::route()->getPrefix() === 'test')
<!-- some html here -->
@endif
```

See: https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_getPrefix